# Adding output from a function to a constant within another function in python

Tags: python, function, input, typeerror

This seems pretty basic, but I can't seem to get it right....

I have two functions which I'm defining in python, both of which are numerical calculations.  The first is straight forward and gives me an output of a figure.  The second is based on what ever output is given from the first plus a constant.

```
def rt(a, b, t):
    #formula to calculate growth rate for brown fish
    #a & b are constants given, t = the month number
    rt = a + (b*sin(((2*pi)*t)/12))
    return rt

def st(brown):
    #formula to calculate growth rate for gold fish
    #rt = output from the growth rates for brown fish
    st = rt + 0.052
    return st
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joanneedes/Documents/Uni Stuff/SCIE1000/Big Project/Big Project Q5a.py", line 41, in <module>
    print st(rt)
  File "/Users/joanneedes/Documents/Uni Stuff/SCIE1000/Big Project/Big Project Q5a.py", line 13, in st
    st = rt + 0.052
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'float'
```

I got given a 'hint' that because rt is a function and 0.052 is a number python doesn't know how to add it up, but I can't find anywhere how to recitfy this - it must be possible, surely!

Comment: This question seems to be very fundamental one of any programming language. You could have got it from any book or from a random search on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to redefine the `st` function, because `rt` is the function, not its result:

```
def st(brown):
    #formula to calculate growth rate for gold fish
    #rt = output from the growth rates for brown fish
    st = rt(a, b, t) + 0.052
    return st
```

Here you call `rt(a,b,t)` and use this result in the sum with 0.052.

It's now your turn to get `a, b, t` out of `brown`.

Comment: Thanks so much all - super helpful - I should have done this hours ago!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `rt` with some parameters, so that it returns a number.

Answer (score 0):

`rt` is a function, you cannot "add it" to a float (that's what the error means).

You have to call it - `rt()` and then use the result in your calculation:

```
def st(brown):
 a = 1
 b = 2
 t = 3
 st = rt(a,b,t) + 0.052
 return st
```

Of course you have to call `rt()` with the correct arguments.